# OCC call is hitting storefront instead of commercewebservices

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, sap-commerce-cloud, storefront

OCC call is hitting `storefront` instead of `commercewebservices`. The call to get token is working perfectly fine but the call to get products or order is saying:

> CMS Site not found

and hitting the filters of `storefront` instead of `commercewebservices`.

***Token call***- https://localhost:9002/authorizationserver/oauth/token

***OCC call***- https://localhost:9002/mycommercewebservices/v2/indsite/products/120398IDC

**EDIT 1**:
I am still getting this issue. Also hitting the extension webroot from hac->extensions is still giving-
https://localhost:9002/mycommercewebservices

> HTTP Status 500 : CMS Site Not Found

I can see all the classes from my `acceleratoraddon/web` in the `addonsrc` folder of `mycommercewebservices`

Answer (score 1):

**Have you changed the web context in mycommercewebservices?**
By default, the Commerce Web Services are available under the `/rest` web context, as specified in the extensioninfo.xml file. So check for the webroot specified in `extensioninfo.xml` of the mycommercewebservices extension.

```
<webmodule jspcompile="false" webroot="/rest" />
```

Refer [this doc](https://help.hybris.com/1808/hcd/8ba212a886691014ba63d7684506c9b6.html)

Comment: Yes, I have changed the web context i.e. webroot to mycommercewebservices. That's why I am hitting the OCC controller with webroot in the URL-
https://localhost:9002/mycommercewebservices/v2/indsite/products/120398IDC
but I am getting "cms site not found" and the calls are hitting storefront instead of commercewebservices.

Comment: Also, cross verify web context from hac > extensions > search for your extension, `/mycommercewebservices` should be there under the web column

Comment: What about property `commercewebservices.rootcontext` changes mentioned [here](https://help.hybris.com/1808/hcd/8ba212a886691014ba63d7684506c9b6.html)?

Comment: Switching off SSL certificates in Postman did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please run ant server (if you hadn't done it before) as the tomcat's server.xml has to be updated with the context entry for your /mycommercewebservices.